# Implementing Phonegap system notification plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to implement this plugin [Phonegap system notification](https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin).

I am calling the `navigator.systemNotification.onBackground()` and `navigator.systemNotification.updateNotification(contentText, tickerText, number)` methods inside my Javascript so that when a new RSS feed title comes up I should get a system notification and an updated counter for each new RSS feed.

1. Right now I get a system notification when a new feed is present but
   when a second feed comes up the counter is not increasing it still
   shows 1 on the notification (icon/image).
2. I want the notification methods to run even in the background, which
   I am not able to test as the counter is not getting updated.
3. I am able to clear the system notification when I click the clear
   button . Is it possible to clear it when the user clicks on the
   system notification?

I think I am doing something wrong in my Javascript.

```
    var oldEntry="";
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function sendRequest(){
      getRss("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_latest.rss.xml");      
      setTimeout('showAlert(newEntry.title)',4000);
    }

    function showAlert(data) {
        var st = randomString();
        if(oldEntry==""){
        oldEntry = data;

            navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();
            navigator.systemNotification.updateNotification(data, 'test' , '1');     
        } else {
            if(oldEntry!=data){
                navigator.notification.alert(
                data,               // message
                    'New Rss Entry',    // title
                    'New Rss Entry');

                oldEntry = data;           
            }
       }

       setTimeout('sendRequest()',7000);
    }

    function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 8;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        return randomstring;
    }

   sendRequest();
```

This is the `systemnotification.js`:

```
function SystemNotification() {
}

SystemNotification.prototype.notificationEnabled = false;

SystemNotification.prototype.newCount = 0; //to keep track of multiple notifications events

SystemNotification.prototype.enableNotification = function () {
    this.notificationEnabled = true;
};

SystemNotification.prototype.disableNotification = function () {
    this.notificationEnabled = false;
};

SystemNotification.prototype.onBackground = function () {
    this.enableNotification();
};

SystemNotification.prototype.onForeground = function () {
    this.disableNotification();
};

SystemNotification.prototype.createStatusBarNotification = function (contentTitle, contentText, tickerText) {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "createStatusBarNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, tickerText]);
};

SystemNotification.prototype.updateNotification = function (contentText, tickerText, number) {
    this.newCount++;
    var contentTitle = "my title";
    if (this.newCount === 1) {
        this.createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
    } else {
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "updateNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, this.newCount]);
        this.showTickerText(tickerText);  //optional
    }
};

SystemNotification.prototype.cancelNotification = function (contentText) {
    this.newCount--;
    if (this.newCount === 0) {
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "cancelNotification", []);
    }
    else {
    //updating the notification
        var contentTitle = "my title";
        PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "updateNotification", [contentTitle, contentText, this.newCount]);
    }
};

SystemNotification.prototype.showTickerText = function (tickerText) {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "showTickerText", [tickerText]);
};

SystemNotification.prototype.touch = function () {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "systemNotification", "touch", []);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function () {
    if (typeof(navigator.systemNotification) == "undefined") {
        navigator.systemNotification = new SystemNotification();
        navigator.systemNotification.touch();  //this ensures that the plugin is added when phonegap kicks off
    }
});
```

This is the `systemnotification.java`:

```
public class SystemNotification extends Plugin {

    final int notif_ID = 1234;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification note;
    PendingIntent contentIntent;

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
    {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";

        try {
            if (action.equals("createStatusBarNotification")) {
                this.createStatusBarNotification(args.getString(0), args.getString(1), args.getString(2));
            }
            else if (action.equals("updateNotification")) {
                this.updateNotification(args.getString(0), args.getString(1), args.getInt(2));
            }
            else if (action.equals("cancelNotification")) {
                this.cancelNotification();
            }
            else if (action.equals("showTickerText")) {
                this.showTickerText(args.getString(0));
            }
            return new PluginResult(status, result);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    private void updateNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText, int number)
    {
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this.ctx, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        note.number = number;
        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    private void createStatusBarNotification(String contentTitle, String contentText, String tickerText)
    {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        note = new Notification(R.drawable.rss, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    //change the icon

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.ctx, Yfs.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.ctx, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this.ctx, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        note.number = 1;  //Just created notification so number=1. Remove this line if you dont want numbers

        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    private void cancelNotification()
    {
        notificationManager.cancel(notif_ID);
    }

    private void showTickerText(String tickerText)
    {
        note.tickerText = tickerText;
        notificationManager.notify(notif_ID,note);
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.webView.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.systemNotification.onBackground();");
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.webView.loadUrl("javascript:navigator.systemNotification.onForeground();");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clearing the notification this is my answer.

On android, you'll need to set the flag `AUTO_CANCEL`

Where you have this

`note = new Notification(R.drawable.rss, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());`

Add this line right under

`note.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

Answer (score 2):

In the SystemNotification.java file just replace the method onPause() for this one :

```
public void onPause()
{
    super.webView.loadUrl("javascript:try{PhoneGap.onResume.fire();}catch(e){};");
    super.webView.resumeTimers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For notification to work in background, your JavaScript should be able to run in background. Solution described at [PhoneGap discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/phonegap/background%2420service/phonegap/KCAf2DhmLD8/YvDWRjcgI5wJ)